# django-enumeields Removing default field makes migration fail with ValueError: '' is not a valid Regions

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a dropdown form to use as a region filter on a project. I got some advice pointing me in the direction of [django-enumfields](https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields). At first, I set a default value for this but I later realized that I need it to not have a default value, due to how I have to design the POST functionality.

I'm using python 3.8.1 and django 3.0.2

This is the relevant code from models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from enumfields import EnumField, Enum

class Regions(Enum):
    LATAM = 'LATAM'
    EU = 'EU'
    NA = 'NA'
    SEA = 'SEA'
    JP = 'JP'
    KR = 'KR'
    ANZ = 'ANZ'
    SK = 'SK'
    NOT_DEF = 'NOT_DEF'

    class Labels:
        LATAM = 'LATAM'
        EU = 'EU'
        NA = 'NA'
        SEA = 'SEA'
        JP = 'JP'
        KR = 'KR'
        SK = 'SK'
        ANZ = 'ANZ'
        NOT_DEF = 'NOT_DEF'

class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    team_region = EnumField(Regions, blank = True, default = Regions.NOT_DEF)
    ...
```

So the only thing I want to change is removing the default value from the Team object:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    team_region = EnumField(Regions, blank = True)
    ...
```

Now, when I try to migrate, I get:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, stats
Running migrations:
  Applying stats.0012_auto_20200204_1426...ValueError: '' is not a valid Regions
```

The migration file looks like this:

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.2 on 2020-02-04 14:05

from django.db import migrations
import enumfields.fields
import stats.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('stats', '0011_auto_20200204_1424'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='team',
            name='team_region',
            field=enumfields.fields.EnumField(blank=True, enum=stats.models.Regions, max_length=10),
        ),
    ]
```

And here's the full stacktrace:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, stats
Running migrations:
  Applying stats.0012_auto_20200204_1426...ValueError: '' is not a valid Regions

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 564, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 679, in _alter_field
    new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 817, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 812, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\enumfields\fields.py", line 70, in get_prep_value
    return self.enum(value).value
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 304, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 595, in __new__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 579, in __new__
    result = cls._missing_(value)
  File "C:\Users\works\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 608, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: '' is not a valid Regions
```

I can't figure out what's wrong here. I doubt this has to do with the database itself and the way I have things set up, I need to remove the default functionality. Any advice?

Comment: does `Team.objects.filter(team_reagion='')` return anything?

Comment: Try using `null=True` and `default=None`, the issue is that by allowing the blank string (`''`) you are required to have a enum value that matches this string. Since you want to be able to have a value that's not one of the enum values `None` seems like a good candidate. (Note that you'll have to regenerate the migration)

Comment: Getting the same error as when I try the migration (ValueError: '' is not a valid Regions)

Comment: null=True and default=None solved the issue. thank you SO much @jaap3